# How to get mega missiles in yellow zone of level 27 in Descent 1?

Tags: descent-1

In level 27, Charon Volatile Mine (last level of the game), behind the yellow door there is a large "room" with several invulnerability boosts and invisibility boosts. This room makes some kind of 8 shape with smart missiles in one of the loop and mega missiles in the other loop. I've been able to get the smart missiles (access from the part of the map where the blue key is), but I've not been able to get to the mega missiles. How can I get them, where is the access?

Answer (score 2):

The access is in the section where the blue key is, in the roof of a dark corridor. From the level spawn point, take the first door to the left. Go down one step and take the door in right in front of you. Follow the very first corridor to the left. The secret door is in the roof of that dark corridor.
See

for video.

Comment: Hi there. You may want to expand this answer beyond just linking the video; if the video is removed, or YouTube dies off in the future, this answer will be useless.

Comment: Added more details, thanks for the feedback.